# How to write a STL-compliant container but its size is unknown?

Tags: c++, stl, standards

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container):

> Any STL-compliant container must provide a member function `size()`.

Now I have to write a STL-compliant container `MyContainer`, `MyContainer::iterator` is a type of `std::input_iterator`, that is, `MyContainer` can only be traversed one pass. For example, I use `MyContainer` to store the result of a SQL query, and use its `iterator` to fecth the records one by one.

I am confronted with such a problem: `MyContainer` can provide `begin()` and `end()` to traverse its values, but cannot pre-determine the total size of its values.

How should I do in such a case?

Comment: This is not a container, you should think in term of iterators rather than container in this case. This should not really be a problem since most of the standard functions use iterators rather than container.

Comment: You need a `stream` rather than a container. You can start with something from `std::istream` based solution.

Comment: `stream` is character-oriented solution, which doesn't fit my issue. I think.

Comment: @xmllmx Why do you want a standard compliant container for this kind of stuff actually?

Comment: @Holt, STL-compliant is always better if possible, I think.

Comment: @xmllmx Compliant maybe, but why a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion around container "requirements" in the C++ standard. While the requirements on iterators are true requirements (e.g., standard algorithms expect that iterators will have certain properties that are defined by the requirements), there is nothing in the standard library that depends on any container satisfying the "container requirements". Those requirements are, in fact, design statements about the particular containers defined in the standard, not requirements in the sense that not meeting them will break code.

Think of containers as a way of providing iterators over a sequence of values. That's important, but it's not the only way to create useful iterators. Input streams, for example, are not containers (and in general don't have a way of determining their size) but they do provide iterators (in the form of `istream_iterator`) that can be passed to standard algorithms. There's nothing wrong with that. Just do it.